# Django model property with parameter

Tags: python, django, properties

I've the following models in Django.

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    ...
    ...

    @property
    def get_info(self, key=None):
        value = self.name if key else 'Hello World'
        return value
```

But when I try to execute the code in Django shell, I'm getting the following error.

```
n [4]: user = User.objects.get(id=1)
n [5]: user.get_info(key='test_key')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-f7b917070aee> in <module>()
----> 1 user.get_info(key='test_key')

TypeError: _get_info() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Just remove the `@property` decorator.  If you need to accept arguments, it's not a property.